# Unable to play video with Youtube player in web app on IOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I built a web app which plays Youtube videos, using Angular YouTube Player with a standard setup. It was working fine, however in last few month several IOS users reported, that video is not playing from my app. No errors appear in logs, Youtube Player shows that infinite loading status. For some users disconnecting from WiFi and using 4G network helped, however this is not a solution. Also video can be played in Youtube app by copying the link, but still it does not work in the browser.
I tried to reproduce the issue, but it works normally for me. Due to unability to reproduce the issue I have to use only this feedback for troubleshooting. Did not find any related issues in Internet.
Did anyone have similar issues with Youtube API on IOS?  
Application code is here: https://github.com/DiReon/go-fit
Application itself: https://regina-go.web.app

Comment: The same thing is happening in my project. The videos are embedded and played inside a webview. I have reports from Android and iOS users with the infinite loading, and only works using 4G or changing Wifi network.
But I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: I suppose issue was with iOS versions, as in January 2022 users reported, that video works without problems. Maybe it is related to the latest updates of iOS. I did not get any reports about issues on Android devices.

Comment: Issue disappeared by itself after several month, looks like it was solved by iOS updates.